# Optimize the performance of dictionary membership for a list of Keys

Tags: python, performance, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to write a code which should return true if any element of list is present in a dictionary. Performance of this piece is really important. I know I can just loop over list and break if I find the first search hit. Is there any faster or more Pythonic way for this than given below?

```
for x in someList:
     if x in someDict:
           return True
return False
```

EDIT: I am using `Python 2.7`. My first preference would be a faster method.

Comment: "any faster or more pythonic way" --- pick one. You cannot have a dress to be both blue and white.

Comment: @zerkms actually there is a famous dress over there that has 2 colors at the same time x). (But this is off topic and I know and agree with you) ;)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use of builtin [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) can have some performance edge over two loops

```
any(x in someDict for x in someList)
```

but you might need to measure your mileage. If your list and dict remains pretty static and you have to perform the comparison multiple times, you may consider using set

```
someSet = set(someList) 
someDict.viewkeys() & someSet
```

**Note** Python 3.X, by default returns views rather than a sequence, so it would be straight forward when using Python 3.X

```
someSet = set(someList) 
someDict.keys() & someSet
```

In both the above cases you can wrap the result with a bool to get a boolean result

```
bool(someDict.keys() & set(someSet ))
```

**Heretic Note**

My curiosity got the better of me and I timed all the proposed solutions. ***It seems that your original solution is better performance wise. Here is the result***

Sample Randomly generated Input

```
def test_data_gen():
    from random import sample
    for i in range(1,5):
        n = 10**i
        population = set(range(1,100000))
        some_list = sample(list(population),n)
        population.difference_update(some_list)
        some_dict = dict(zip(sample(population,n),
                             sample(range(1,100000),n)))
        yield "Population Size of {}".format(n), (some_list, some_dict), {}
```

### The Test Engine

I rewrote the Test Part of the answer as it was messy and the answer was receiving quite a decent attention. I created a timeit compare python module and moved it onto [github](https://github.com/itabhijitb/comptimeit/tree/master/comptimeit)

### The Test Result

```
Timeit repeated for 10 times
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_nested           |0.000011  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_any      |0.000014  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.000015  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_imap_any         |0.000018  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_any              |0.000019  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_ifilter_next     |0.000022  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.000024  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.000047  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 100
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_ifilter_any      |0.000071  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_nested           |0.000072  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.000073  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_next     |0.000076  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_imap_any         |0.000082  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_any              |0.000092  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.000170  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.000638  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 1000
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.000746  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_any      |0.000746  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_next     |0.000752  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_nested           |0.000771  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_set_ashwin       |0.000838  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_imap_any         |0.000842  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_any              |0.000933  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.001702  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10000
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_nested           |0.007195  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_next     |0.007410  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_any      |0.007491  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.007671  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_set_ashwin       |0.008385  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_imap_any         |0.011327  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_any              |0.011533  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.018313  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
Timeit repeated for 100 times
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_nested           |0.000098  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_any      |0.000124  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.000131  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_imap_any         |0.000142  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_ifilter_next     |0.000151  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_any              |0.000158  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.000186  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.000496  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 100
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_ifilter_any      |0.000661  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.000677  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_nested           |0.000683  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_next     |0.000684  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_imap_any         |0.000762  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_any              |0.000854  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.001291  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.005018  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 1000
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_ifilter_any      |0.007585  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_nested           |0.007713  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_set_ashwin       |0.008256  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.008526  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_any              |0.009422  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_ifilter_next     |0.010259  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_imap_any         |0.011414  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.019862  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10000
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_imap_any         |0.082221  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_any      |0.083573  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_nested           |0.095736  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_set_ashwin       |0.103427  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_ifilter_next     |0.104589  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.117974  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_any              |0.127739  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.208228  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
Timeit repeated for 1000 times
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_nested           |0.000953  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_any      |0.001134  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.001213  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_next     |0.001340  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_imap_any         |0.001407  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_any              |0.001535  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.002252  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.004701  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 100
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_ifilter_any      |0.006209  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_next     |0.006411  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.006657  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_nested           |0.006727  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_imap_any         |0.007562  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_any              |0.008262  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.012260  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.046773  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 1000
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.071888  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_next     |0.072150  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_nested           |0.073382  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_any      |0.075698  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_set_ashwin       |0.077367  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_imap_any         |0.090623  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_any              |0.093301  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.177051  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10000
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_nested           |0.701317  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_next     |0.706156  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_any      |0.723368  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.746650  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_set_ashwin       |0.776704  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_imap_any         |0.832117  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_any              |0.881777  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |1.665962  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
Timeit repeated for 10000 times
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_nested           |0.010581  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_any      |0.013512  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_imap_any         |0.015321  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.017680  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_ifilter_next     |0.019334  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_any              |0.026274  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.030881  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.053605  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 100
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_nested           |0.070194  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.078524  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_any      |0.079499  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_imap_any         |0.087349  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_ifilter_next     |0.093970  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_any              |0.097948  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |0.130725  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |0.480841  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 1000
======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result    |Description
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_ifilter_any      |0.754491  |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_ifilter_not_not  |0.756253  |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_ifilter_next     |0.771382  |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_nested           |0.787152  |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_set_ashwin       |0.818520  |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_imap_any         |0.902947  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_any              |1.001810  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_set              |2.012781  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
=======================================
Test Run for Population Size of 10000
=======================================
|Rank  |FunctionName         |Result     |Description
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     1|foo_imap_any         |10.071469  |any(imap(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     2|foo_any              |11.127034  |any(x in some_dict for x in some_list)
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     3|foo_set              |18.881414  |some_dict.viewkeys() & set(some_list )
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     4|foo_nested           |8.731133   |Original OPs Code
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     5|foo_ifilter_not_not  |9.019190   |not not next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     6|foo_ifilter_next     |9.189966   |bool(next(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__...
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     7|foo_set_ashwin       |9.363886   |not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)
+------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
|     8|foo_ifilter_any      |9.442759   |any(ifilter(some_dict.__contains__, some_list))
```

And a Graphical Comparison from the above referred module

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Conclusion

Premature optimization is evil. It is evident that none of the solutions have optimal performance when the test domain varies. Depending on population size and frequency of iteration, performance of solutions varies considerably. The result again speaks out about the fact that in Python, one should ensure that the code should be readable rather than ensuring that the code is either nifty or optimized for performance for certain cases, but then it may not be scalable.

**Note** There were some doubts on why not using ifilter performs better than the rest

> "In Abhit's answer, he timed the different approaches and found that
> ifilter/next was not the fastest; any idea why this would be the case?
> "

It is a known fact that in python, there is an overhead when calling C functions, and if the population size is low but the frequency of iteration is high, the accumulation of C function call overhead would slowly show up. As can be seen in the graphs, where population size is low but iteration is high, using ifilter, performance deviates considerably.

Comment: If my list and dicts are quite dynamic and changing a lot then is the first option my best bet?

Comment: The timeit results are quite interesting. I would probably use nested or any then.

Comment: Does it matter that `from itertools import ifilter` is called each time inside the `def foo_ifilter`? Might as well move that outside. Also, could use `not not` like Raymond suggested.

Comment: `foo_ifilter` shouldn't be the slowest solution. I guess it happens because of import. You might want to move it to the module level

Comment: @Alik: Corrected. I had that is mind but forgot to remove it.

Comment: Instead of `set.intersection` I would use `set.isdisjoint`: `not set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)`. Dictviews are slow because there you're calling `set()` on both `dict` and list(implicitly and explictly), OTOH `set(some_dct).isdisjoint(some_lst)` will convert `some_dict` to set first and then we loop over `some_list`'s items and check if it is contained in the set, if yes short-circuit.

Comment: Please add to the list Raymond's latest revision: `any(ifilter(someDict.__contains__, someList))`

Comment: @twasbrillig: I added the revised version in the list.

Comment: On your next iteration you could edit ifilter/all to ifilter/any - also "Use of builtin any can have some performance edge over two loops any(x in someDict for x in someList)" should probably be edited to mention it was before the tests - also latest latest @RaymondHettinger iteration with `itertools.imap() instead of ifilter()` - could it be the winner ?

Comment: In the updated version both [`foo_set`](https://github.com/itabhijitb/comptimeit/blob/master/comptimeit/__init__.py#L13) and [`foo_set_ashwin`](https://github.com/itabhijitb/comptimeit/blob/master/comptimeit/__init__.py#L15) have the same code now, i.e the disjoint version is missing.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yes, I might have missed when rewriting and assimilating the codes.

Comment: Other than making the answer long and colorful, what is the point of showing any of the timings fewer than 10,000 repetitions?  Fewer repetitions just means that the measurements have more noise.  Those ought to be removed from the answer (or a least move the most reliable measurements to the top rather than leaving them at the end).

Answer (score 10):

The cleanest and fastest way is to use [*any()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) and [*itertools.ifilter()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter):

```
any(ifilter(someDict.__contains__, someList))
```

This code uses:

- a bound method, `someDict.__contains__` as the predicate
- the *ifilter()* itertool lazily scans for a true result at C speed
- the *any()* built-in drives the filter to find a single matching occurrence or to return *False* if the iterator is exhausted.

You could also use *itertools.imap()* instead of *ifilter()*.

Comment: I'd be interested in the fastest way if there is even 10-20% speed improvement. Could you please edit the answer with the specific for ifilter?

Comment: In Abhit's answer, he timed the different approaches and found that ifilter/next was not the fastest; any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: @twasbrillig: Refer my answer now, and take a note of the conclusion from  the data analysis.

Comment: The conclusion was knowable in advance.  For short sequences, pure python wins because it has no function call overhead.  For long sequences, itertools wins because it has no interpreter loop overhead (it was specifically designed to solve this problem).  You don't need 30 timings and graphs to know how it is going to turn-out.  Also the "why" is more important that the actual timing (so that the knowledge can be applied elsewhere).

Answer (score 4):

```
s = set(someList)
return bool(s.intersection(someDict.keys()))
```